# How to get text outside tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Want to get text which is outside a tag. Here is the HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
       class="viewingsCommentsTbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b style="border: 2px solid red; 
                  background: rgb(204, 136, 136);">Viewing Conducted: </b>
        18-May-2016
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style=""><b style="">Duration: </b> 1 hr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style=""><b style="">Comments: </b>66yy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**I wanted to get date i.e `"18-May-2016"`**

I tried following XPath, but it does not work:

```
//*[@class="viewingsCommentsTbl"]/tbody/tr[1]/td/b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is in the `<td>` tag, not the `<b>`. Try

```
//*[@class="viewingsCommentsTbl"]/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try it like below

```
WebElement dateis = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='viewingsCommentsTbl']/tbody/tr/td"));
System.out.println("Date is : " + dateis.getText());
```

and the output is : Date is : Viewing Conducted: 18-May-2016

// also if want to extract date only then

```
String [] extractdate = dateis.getText().split(" ");
System.out.println("Extracted date is : " + extractdate[2]);
```

and the output is : Extracted date is : 18-May-2016

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***more robust*** way to select `"18-May-2016"` based on its preceding `Viewing Conducted:` label within a `td` in the `viewingsCommentsTbl` table ***independent of
    table layout***:

```
normalize-space(
   substring-after(//table[@class='viewingsCommentsTbl']
                   //td[starts-with(.,'Viewing Conducted:')],'Viewing Conducted:'))
```

This gets the text outside of a tag (per your request) by selecting the string value of the element's parent and then using `substring-after()` to get just the text that follows the label.